How do I replace app bundle before resubmitting a release for review in Google Play Console?
I uploaded a new bundle, but it is not set to active:

How do I make sure my updated bundle is what gets submitted when I resubmit my release for review?
I tried following these instructions but I got lost on Step 3.3, since there was no "View Release Dashboard" button that it says to click.
Do I just need to create a new release, instead of editing the current release? Previously I edited screen shots and the description, and resubmitted the same release, so I assume I can change the bundle and resubmit the same release.
I have contacted Google Play's customer support. If I get a good answer from them, I will post it here.
This question is basically the same as another question from 4 years ago, but the answer does not work for me. I could not find "Release management > App release > Production track > Manage > Edit release" anywhere on the Google Play Console, must have been changes made in the past 4 years.
